# Actualizar mi DataGrid en C# sin usar botones

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-forms, datagrid

os comento estoy intentando actualizar mi datagrid sin la necesidad de dar a ningún botón. Este datagrid se rellena haciendo llamadas a una base de datos. 
Se me había ocurrido usar threads para en segundo plano ir actualizando las llamadas cada cierto tiempo como si fuera un tiempo de refresco de pantalla.

```
    private void recargar()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = getconnection();
            dataGrid1.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
        }
    }
```

El problema es que así o creando un thread nuevo nunca termina y no saca por pantalla la tabla (la interfaz), se queda en ejecución contante. 
Entonces mi pregunta es que como puedo hacer para desde el main llamar a recargar y que realice el thread sin que impida que salga la tabla y así cada cierto tiempo cambien los valores de la tabla.

ya de paso alguien sabe como puedo hacer para que se ajuste el texto al tamaño del datagrid ?

Comment: Pienso que puedes hacer esto, haciendo uso del control `Timer` del Cuadro de Herramientas, estableces un tiempo en que invoque dicha función `recargar`

Comment: _El problema es que así o creando un thread nuevo nunca termina_ esto se debe a que tienes esto `while (true) { ...}` siempre será verdadero, por eso nunca termina, ese While no es necesario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el evento `load` de tu formulario has esto:

```
Timer actualizar_automatico = new Timer(); 

private void TuForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //........
     actualizar_automatico.Interval = 3000;
     actualizar_automatico.Tick += actualizar_automatico_Tick;
     actualizar_automatico.Enabled = true; 
}
```

Tú función seria así:

```
private void recargar()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = getconnection();
    dataGrid1.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
}
```

Luego quedaría el evento que ejecutará la función de forma automática:

```
private void actualizar_automatico_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
   recargar(); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Mil gracias a todos !! he conseguido arreglarlo con la herramienta Time al final

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = getconnection();
        dataGrid1.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(recargar); 
        timer.Interval = (1000) * (1);              
        timer.Enabled = true;                       
        timer.Start();                              
    }
```

Comment: Pero eso va a bloquear la interfaz cada que lea de la base de datos